# publish android libraries with flavors

Tags: android, android-library, android-flavors

is it possible to publish android libraries with flavors? My initial test with jitpack that I usually use to publish libraries failed. Can anyone point me to a working example of a setup like this?

Got the flavors working locally inside one project - but publishing seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it's possible.

Jitpack essentially calls `./gradlew install` and then looks for artifacts.
The trick is to define the artifacts and then to know how to locate them.

Here's a sample project with multi-flavor-multi-project on jitpack:
https://github.com/mirceanis/multi-flavor-lib-demo

There's a single-library functional sample in the [single-lib](https://github.com/mirceanis/multi-flavor-lib-demo/tree/single-lib) branch